# Отображение длинного массива, подключения массива в .txt формате

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, visual-studio-code

Столкнулся с такой проблемой (уточняю что в деве не долго), в общем, у меня есть массив, длиною в 1000+ строк, если я его размещаю в длину, в програме VS code, у меня появляется ошибка, так как в одной строке VS code если я не ошибаюсь вмещается 9999 символов, что намного меньше чем у меня в массиве. Массив вставляется в код одной строкой и уходит за пределы видимости экрана, а в случае если я его делаю короче то выбивает ошибку "Line is too long. (W101)", и мне приходится оставлять в одной линии по 10 ячеек массива, что делает мой код длиннее на 500+ строк. Вопрос, как справится с этим, так как в ручную ставить ентеры через 10 ячеек массива очень затратно по времени. Также возможно подскажите как подключить массив из внешнего .txt файла локально на компе с папки в которой .js и возможно ли его сразу превратить в массив. К сожалению на этот вопрос я не нашёл ответа в интернетах, возможно плохо искал, но пока так...

Сразу спасибо за ваше время.

Answer (score 0):

Даже если подключить массив как дополнительно загружаемый js-файл, то всё равно потребуется форматирование, согласно требованию к синтаксису кода в JavaScript.

Самое простое, если массив всегда постоянен на старте загрузки во фронт, то потратьте время, и разместите этот массив внутри основного js-файла, заканчивая каждую строку запятой и расходуя максимально доступное количество символов (9999) на размещение в одной строке.

Таким образом, отпадёт необходимость в сопровождении дополнительного файла + повысится скорость загрузки фронта в браузер.

```
aArray = ["111", "zzz", 
"p4p"]
```